# Selenium grid opens blank page with no URL while only chrome runs the tests

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I was trying to run test concurrently with two browsers firefox and chrome. I had opened three command line windows with following commands
1. java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role

1. java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role webdriver -hub localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName="chrome", version=8.0, platform=WINDOWS -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=f:\chromedriver.exe
2. java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role webdriver -hub 
       localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5566

I had following code in GridTest.java file

```
    public static String browser;
    public static void setUp() throws MalformedURLException //throws MalformedURLException
    {
//      if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
//      {
        DesiredCapabilities capability1=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capability1= DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capability1.setBrowserName("firefox");
        capability1.setPlatform(Platform.WIN8);
        driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), capability1);
//      }
//      
//      if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
//      {
        capability1=DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capability1.setBrowserName("chrome");
        capability1.setPlatform(Platform.WIN8);
        driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), capability1);
//      }
    }
```

Do I have to open another command line window if I have to run test in IE? Can test be run concurrently with testng.xml? Please provide the solution

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, solved by Updating the "Chromedriver.exe".

Note: Even if you update to the latest chromedriver.exe, make sure that your project points to the latest one. (the project could be pointing to old diver)

Answer (score 0):

crazvink,
1. you don't have to open a new command line window for each browser you can just concat the browser type in one NODE process like this:

*java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar -role node -browser browserName=firefox,version=3.6,maxInstances=5,platform=WINDOWS -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=5,platform=WINDOWS -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=f:\chromedriver.exe*

1. you should only run another command line window for hub.
2. of course you *can* do it, but then you need to manipulate ports (like you did) which is unnecessary, in such a simple case.

yes, running in parallel is very simple, but you need to make sure the webdrivers are instantiated in the test methods themselves, using dataprovider for each different browser/platform type. and then just set parallel=methods in the testing.xml (testNg?).
*this is an optional solution, it can be dome in many more ways (like class factory, and parallel=instances).

note this : running in parallel on the same display might be problematic since browsers focus can be interfered between tests :(.

anyway maybe you will find this helpful too: http://www.ravellosystems.com/blog/build-effective-web-ui-testing-lab/

for building your testing grid lab without the hassle and scaling it as you go.

[Disclosure : i work for Ravello.]